# GDB missing serparate debuginfo after installing all debuginfo

Tags: gdb, rhel, openssh

I'm trying to use GDB with openssh on rhel 8. I have installed all openssh and openssl debuginfo packages and that works fine to find breakpoints. However, as soon as gdb hits the first breakpoint it throws an error with about 30 missing debuginfo with a yum command. I quit, copy-paste the command, all debuginfo packages install properly and I try again. gdb tells me all the packages I just installed are missing. I'm not sure how to fix it and I'm stuck.
Would anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to grab the gcc-toolset-*-gdb build of gdb 10+, you can take advantage of `debuginfod` support to download & use debuginfo.  No need to install all those RPMs manually.

```
sudo yum -y install gcc-toolset-10-gdb
export DEBUGINFOD_URLS=https://debuginfod.elfutils.org/
scl enable gcc-toolset-10 -- gdb [...]
```