# debuginfod-find work, but gdb can not find the symbols?

Tags: gdb

I use this process to build & setup debuginfod

```
gcc -g foo.c -o foo
objcopy --only-keep-debug foo foo.dbg
strip foo
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=foo.dbg foo
mkdir srv
mv foo.dbg srv
debuginfod -F srv/foo.dbg > debuginfod.log 2>&1 &
DEBUGINFOD_URLS=http://localhost:8002
gdb foo
```

output of `debuginfod-find -v debuginfo foo`  workable

```
debuginfod_find_debuginfo b4c57580d6dbd0a19d0e41b38ec33cc7b992bfc8
server urls "http://localhost:8002"
checking build-id
checking cache dir /home/example/.cache/debuginfod_client
found /home/example/.cache/debuginfod_client/b4c57580d6dbd0a19d0e41b38ec33cc7b992bfc8/debuginfo (fd=4)
/home/example/.cache/debuginfod_client/b4c57580d6dbd0a19d0e41b38ec33cc7b992bfc8/debuginfo
```

output of `gdb foo`

```
Reading symbols from foo...Missing separate debuginfo for /home/example/tmp/foo/foo
Try: yum --enablerepo='*debug*' install /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/b4/c57580d6dbd0a19d0e41b38ec33cc7b992bfc8.debug
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

About the version

```
gdb --version # 8.2-18.el8
debuginfod_client --version  # 0.186.
```

Related rpm(Rocky Linux)

- gdb-8.2-18.el8.x86_64
- elfutils-debuginfod-client-0.186-1.el8.x86_64
- elfutils-debuginfod-0.186-1.el8.x86_64
- gcc-8.5.0-10.1.el8_6.x86_64

My current workaround is

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file /home/example/.cache/debuginfod_client/b4c57580d6dbd0a19d0e41b38ec33cc7b992bfc8/debuginfo
```

Comment: And your gdb is built with debuginfod support?

Comment: Maybe, but, I don't know how to check it.

Comment: In gdb, do `show configuration`. Or try `set debuginfod enabled on`, it will tell you if it's not compiled in.

Comment: You need GDB 10.1 or newer. Does Rocky Linux have RHEL-like Software Collections? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67984934/gdb-missing-serparate-debuginfo-after-installing-all-debuginfo/69487513#69487513

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, maybe you answered this question.  But, I won't plan to upgrade gcc, because it is main long term for RHEL 8.x (Rocky Linux 8.x)